# How to send requests from Nginx reverse proxy to a server with Apache instances

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I want to use an Nginx server configured as a reverse proxy to send requests to an Apache server which hosts multiple web pages. The scenario is as follows:

- A webserver with the DNS address host.example.com which servers a static web page.
- A webapp running on the aforementioned server. A CNAME record webapp.target.com points to host.example.com. When this is entered into a browser, the correct webapp is returned (different to the static page).
- An Nginx server with an entry that directs webapp-proxy.example.com to webapp.target.com (with a corresponding DNS entry, pointing webapp-proxy.example.com to the Nginx server).

With my current setup, when I access webapp-proxy.example.com in a browser I am redirected to host.example.com. Instead I want to be redirected to webapp.target.com.

I currently have this config setup (edited to remove unnecessary info: SSL, caching etc). I am assuming there is an additional header I need to set. This is currently run on a local network, but eventually this proxy will be used to allow internet users access to the site.

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name webapp-proxy.example.com;
    rewrite ^(.*) https://$server_name$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen      443 ssl;
    server_name webapp-proxy.example.com;

    ssl                 on;
    ssl_certificate     /path/to/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded_For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded_Proto https;

        proxy_pass       http://webapp.target.com;
}
```

Comment: Replace `proxy_set_header Host $host;` with `proxy_set_header Host webapp.target.com;` or simply remove it.

Comment: @IvanShatsky removing it caused the same problem. Modifying the `Host` header as you suggested was the correct solution.